# Group Policy Client Service Failed

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, login, restore

I recently got a new computer, but someone had already created a user account. Instead of deleting theirs and creating a new one, I just changed the name. Next I need to change the `C:\Users\TheirName` to be my name, so I went to the registry and changed `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` `ProfileImagePath` in `regedit` to my own folder.

When I restarted my computer, I tried to go into my user account (the only one), and it came up with

> The group policy client service failed to login

when I tried to login. So then I restarted my computer in recovery and tried to change it back, but I can't access that registry value in recovery (It is `X:` instead of `C:`, and I can't change drives).

How can I change it back?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and create a new user account for yourself and delete the one you're currently trying to get working.

Comment: I would do that, except it was my only account and I can't access another one or make another in recovery.

Comment: I decided to restart to factory settings. I will see if that works.

Comment: Factory Reset worked. I shouldn't have messed with the registry like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to factory reset. Basically I just messed with a registry value and it locked me out of my system because of a change in the user folder location. Not that big of a deal, but I learned not to mess with the registry like this. So, if you have this problem, you may need to reset. If you need to get on, find a way to remotely (flash drive OS perhaps, tried it but abandoned it) or give up.